# Gradle sync fails after upgrading Android Studio to Arctic Fox

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I tried to do a Gradle sync after the Android Studio upgrade and the following message

```
Value '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)
```

is shown in the build fail window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I have set up a custom java home path for my Gradle pointing to the bundled JDK and the path has changed beginning from Arctic Fox.

Found this in my `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/
```

and it should now be replaced to:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/
```

Comment: OMG thx this has been driving me insane today